# Use Redux state to initialize Axios client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have a React/Electron application I'm working on in which I want to use data from my Redux store to initialize my Axios client. The use case is, for example, on first load of the app the user enters some information, like their username. This is pushed to the Redux store (and persisted in `localStorage` for future use), then used in the `baseURL` of the axios client for subsequent network requests.

The problem is, I can't get axios to work with react-redux and the `connect()` function. Axios' function exports seem to be hidden by the exported HOC, and any time I call one of its functions I get the following error:

```js
TypeError: _Client2.default.get is not a function
```

My client looks something like this:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Client = ({ init }) => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://${init.ip}/api/${init.username}`
  });
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { init: state.init };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Client);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Here in react-redux documentation https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns it says that `The return of connect() is a wrapper function that takes your component and returns a wrapper component with the additional props it injects.` So it returns react component that wraps react component. Your function returns axios client, it doesn't render anything.

I prefer to use action creators and make api calls there(Therefore I don't pass axios client or whatever). But if I decided to that I would initialize axios client inside reducer and keep in the store. And then pass it to clients as props.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { axios: state.axios };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of @Ozan's answer, In this case what you can do is create a main component, connect it with redux and dispatch an action on mount to initialize axios client.

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate AXIOS client before you load App.js. I recommend you can use redux-axios as redux middleware and use action to call api.

https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware